# Emails from another organization are being returned

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, exchange, exchange-2003

We are running Exchange 2003 on a Windows Server 2003 server.  In the last week or so, one outside organization has started getting errors when sending to us.

The log from their end when sending a test message is at http://pastebin.com/XSHuVkbR and the log from our end on a failed message is at http://pastebin.com/yaJSGqV6, both obfuscated for privacy.

We have no trouble sending to them.

I have checked on our DNS records to make sure that everything is pointing correctly, also that noone has us blacklisted as a spammer, but nothing comes up.  This company is the only one that can't send to us, and from what they say, we are the only ones they can't send do.

Nothing has been changed in some time with regard to our email setup, so I'm stumped right now.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So the connection closes right after the From and Rcpt To is announced?  This sounds similar to a situation I ran into a while back where our IP somehow got on Trend's DUL list: https://ers.trendmicro.com/  Check your IP there and also find out if the remote party is using any email gateway service like Trend and check there.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I did check on that, and specifically with Trend's now that you mentioned it, but we don't seem to be on any blacklists.

Comment: What is LOCAL-EXCHANGE-FQDN [LOCAL-EXCHANGE-IP]?

Comment: Those are the FQDN and IP address for my exchange server, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Are those 2 logs for the same email?  I ask because yours looks like they connected ok to you, but theirs seems to be a Postfix server (possibly running Astaro?) that is timing out connecting to you.  That makes me think it is a DNS issue on their end trying to properly find you.  They might consider flushing their DNS cache on their mail servers and gateways and making sure the proper records are being returned.

Of course, like any other IT issue that states "just started happening recently", verify what has changed, if anything, on both sides (DNS, app updates, network changes, firewall/router updates, etc.) that might point you in the right direction.

If the above fails, I would increase the debug logging on both sides along with looking at any debug logs on the WAN network gear during the traffic session and see what is going on to cause them to timeout trying to reach you.

Comment: Yes, those logs are from the same email.  They are the same every time a test is sent.  Fortunately, I'm the only tech at this end so I know that there weren't any settings changed on anything related to the email server in weeks, and I have been told that nothing has changed on their end.  I had thought about their server timing out and agree with you there.  I wanted to make sure before I said anything though.